# neovim automatically providing input when executing a .out file

Tags: c++, vim, neovim

I did not provide any user input after the command and it did not wait for any user input and it automatically gave 32766 as input

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcClJ.png)

but when I run the main.cpp.out file from the terminal it waits for input and works fine.
I tried it with vim and it works fine. I think there is some issue with neovim.

my neovim config file:

```
source $HOME/.config/nvim/vim-plug/plugins.vim
source $HOME/.config/nvim/themes/airline.vim 
:map<C-n> :NERDTree<CR>
set number 
"Compile and Run
set autowrite
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> :!g++ -std=c++14 % -Wall -g -o %.out<CR>
autocmd filetype python nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> :!python3 %<CR>
```

I also tried the exact same program on another pc with a fresh install of neovim and the problem seemed to continue.

Comment: Thank you. Generally you should ***never*** post any text (code, input / output, or error messages) as images here.

Comment: If you have important additional information, prefer to [edit] your question again and add it there, rather than in comments on the question, Comments are meant to ask for clarificatio from other commenters, or the author of a post (question or answer).